# Nice way to deal with possible return values of void in a generic function?

Tags: c++, templates

I was working on some generic code and thought it'd make a nice interface for a set of classes I plan to use in a variant if I could have a bunch of functions with the same name and parameters, but potentially different return types. For instance, maybe I'd like to have three classes that implement a function that might return `int` or `std::vector<int>` or `void`, where the returns represent some sequence of signals that propagate outwards in a system.

```
struct X{
    //...
    int update(double){
        return 5;
    }
};
struct Y{
    //...
    void update(double){
        //Do something useful
    }
};
struct Z{
    //...
    std::vector<int> update(double){
        return {1,2,3,4};
    }
};
```

Then, at some later point, I might have a generic function (e.g. acting as a visitor to a variant) like

```
template<class T>
void updateHandler(T& object){
    auto ret = object.update(3.14);
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(ret), int>){
        //Do something with an integer.
    }else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(ret), std::vector<int> >){
        //Do something with a vector of integers
    }
}
```

But this won't work if `updateHandler` is called on an object of type `Y` because `auto` will deduce as `void`. While it's possible to test for the condition that the return type is void early via `decltype`, this would result in something like

```
template<class T>
void updateHandler(T& object){
    if constexpr(std::is_void_v<decltype(object.update())>){
        object.update();
    }else{
        auto ret = object.update();
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(ret), int>){
            //Do something with an integer.
        }else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(ret), std::vector<int> >){
            //Do something with a vector of integers
        }
    }
}
```

where it's not as clear exactly what we're doing and somehow we've managed to duplicate our entire function call three times (!) in the code without being able to reduce this number in any obvious way.

I also had hoped that maybe there might be some funky rules to deal with this case, the same way that one can pass on a `void` return value in generic in the same way that

```
[](auto& object){ return object.update(3.14); }
```

is legal - I tried, for instance, using a template that might convert voids to values

```
template<class T>
decltype(auto) coverVoid(T&& input){
    return input;
}
std::monostate coverVoid(void){
    return {};
}
```

but this doesn't work since `void` isn't actually an argument (and I wouldn't really expect it to work, since `void` is, an incomplete type and you can't take a reference to it either). The best thing I could think of would be to hide all the repetition in a generic such as:

```
template<class Call, class Handle>
void handleMaybeVoid(Call&& call, Handle&& handle){
    if constexpr(std::is_void_v<decltype(call())>){
        call();
        //Could then call handle(); if we wanted to handle void
    }else{
        handle(call());
    }
}
```

and invoke that to implement `updateHandler`.

While I think there's an easy enough solution to this problem (just return an empty type instead of `void` in `update` - though this leads to a rather useless `return {};` line), it surprises me that a `void` return seems to be so hard to handle in generic code. Is there a better way to deal with return values that are possibly void?

Comment: It seems that `handleMaybeVoid` is the way to go.